# $|z_{1}- z_{2}| \leq |w_{1}- w_{2}| \implies |c_{1}z_{1}- c_{2}z_{2}| \leq |c_{1}w_{1}- c_{2} w_{2}|$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality

Let $z_{1}, z_{2}, w_{1}, w_{2} \in \mathbb C$ with $|z_{1}- z_{2}| \leq |w_{1}- w_{2}|.$
Fix $c_{1}, c_{2}\in (0, \infty).$

> **My Question is**: Can we expect, $|c_{1}z_{1}- c_{2}z_{2}| \leq |c_{1}w_{1}- c_{2} w_{2}|$ ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No.  Let $z_1 = 1, z_2 = 2, w_1 = 0, w_2 = 4$.

Then $|z_1 z_2| = 1 < 4 = |w_1 - w_2|$ and yet let $c_1 = 1, c_2 = 0$, we have $|c_1 z_1| > |c_1 w_1|$.

Comment: We can't take $c_1, c_2$ as $0$, can we?

Comment: $c_2 =  0.0000000001$

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, and I think that is correct, but you need to give a better example.

Comment: How about $c_2 = 0.125$ ?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Let
$$
z_1=2,\,\,z_2=2,\,\,w_1=1,\,\,w_2=0, \,\,c_1=1,\,\,c_2=3.
$$
Then
$$
\lvert z_1-z_2\rvert=0<1=\lvert w_1-w_2\rvert,
$$
while
$$
\lvert c_1z_1-c_2z_2\rvert=4>1=\lvert c_1w_1-c_2w_2\rvert.
$$